# group and sort divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, slidesjs

I have a series of 6 slides within a jquery slider. (http://www.slidesjs.com/)

Techincally speaking these are 6 individual slides however the slides are in pairs

```
Group 1 = Slides 1 + 2
Group 2 = Slides 3 + 4
Group 3 = Slides 5 + 6
```

I am trying to randomise the order of Group 1,2 and 3 but the slides have to remain in the correct order within these groups.

The current markup is

```
 <div id="slides">
    <div class="slide">
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
    </div>
     <div class="slide">
    </div>
 </div>
```

I could randomise all slides however this could lead to the slides being jumbled and not paired.

Could this be done with data-attributes? I am not sure what method I could use to do this.

Comment: Just wrap `.slide` to something like `.group`, then random those `.group` instead of `.slide`.

Comment: You cannot do that because the the .group becomes the slide not .slide

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "jquery slider"? Is [this](https://jqueryui.com/slider/) what you're talking about?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear about that bit! I am using: http://www.slidesjs.com/ Image slider

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [documentation](http://www.slidesjs.com/) on that site there is an option to allow you to specify the starting slide so you could randomize the starting group but you would still have to keep the sequence from then on.

To do this you could do:

```
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

$(function(){
    var slidesPerGroup = 2;

    $("#slides").slidesjs({
        start: (getRandomInt(1, 3) * slidesPerGroup) - 1
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

it's not beautiful, well... just a possible way (http://jsfiddle.net/bukart/c0fjq19p/1/)

```
var order = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]];

$(function() {
    var neworder = [], oldorder = [];

    oldorder = order; // better you clone here ;)

    while (oldorder.length) {
        var n = Math.floor(Math.random() * oldorder.length);
        neworder.push(oldorder[n]);
        oldorder.splice(n, 1);
    }

    var $slideBox = $('#slides');
    var $slides = $('.slide', $slideBox);

    $slides.detach();

    var $slidesArr = [];
    $slides.each(function() {
        $slidesArr.push($(this));
    });
    for (i = 0; i < neworder.length; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < neworder[i].length; j++) {
            $slideBox.append($slidesArr[neworder[i][j]-1]);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create your own navigation controls to make this work. View source on [this page](http://thinsoldier.github.io/externals/slidesjs/examples/thn-api-access/) for an example of how this can be done. It's going to look something like this:

```
<div class="controls">
    <button class="prev">Prev</button>
    <button class="next">Next</button>
</div>

<script>
    function selectSlide() {
        var slides = [1, 3, 5]; // This function picks a random number from this array.
        var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * slides.length);
        return slides[randomIndex];
    }
    $(function() {
        $('#slides').slidesjs({
            width: 940,
            height: 528,
            navigation: {active: false},
        });
        var sjs = $('#slides').data('plugin_slidesjs'); // you can issue commands to the slideshow through this variable
        $('.controls .next').click(function(){
            var currentPage = sjs.data.current;
            console.log("Current page:", currentPage);
            switch (currentPage) {
                case 0:
                case 2:
                case 3:
                    console.log("Going to next slide");
                    sjs.next();
                    break;
                default:
                    console.log("Going to a random slide");
                    sjs.goto(selectSlide());
                    break;
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```